# Download and save files for offline usage

Tags: ios, download, soundcloud

I would like download my audios from SoundCloud account to my IOS app. There is a property in soundcloud API (download_url) that allows me to download and the link load the file in browser  but it's not work in iPhone/iPad as mentioned in their site.

Can anyone here help me find a way to download my audio from soundcloud to my iphone app?

Also, I tried to use NSData to save the files and re-read and play them again but I could't determine if the downloading happened or saved? I have nothing to indicate that downloading process is working.

Any ideas about downloading and save files to play in offline mode?

Comment: There's not enough information in this for any kind of help, sorry. You'll have to be specific about what you're trying to download, how you're doing it, and what exactly isn't working. Use specific code examples from your specific application.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify @JasonCoco

Answer (score 0):

SoundCloud have beautiful ios Sdk [SoundCloud docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart). In docs written all you need. No need to reinvent the wheel))).

Comment: I already worked with the API but about the download they said http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/645892-can-i-download-my-sounds-to-my-ipod-iphone-or-ipad- .. I am looking for a way . there are apps allow downloading but I don't know how!!

Comment: You need create connection and get token for user

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to read the SDK itself.

What you really should be asking is how to properly call the following. try this out.
I have NOT tested this. Only guessing.

```
NSString *streamURL = [track objectForKey:@"stream_url"];
SCAccount *account = [SCSoundCloud account];
[SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET 
              onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:streamURL] 
         usingParameters:nil 
             withAccount:account 
  sendingProgressHandler:nil 
         responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
             if (err == nil) {

                 if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath]) {
                     NSLog(@"Overwriting for import.");
                     BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:localPath error:nil];
                     if (success) {
                         NSLog(@"Overwrite successful!");
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"Overwrite failed");
                         return;
                     }
                 }
                 BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:localPath contents:data attributes:nil];
                 if (success) {
                     NSLog(@"download complete");
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"failed to create a new file");
                 }
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Failed to download track.");
             }
}];
```